# Where do I customize the Plone welcome email message?

Tags: plone

Where do I customize the message that new users receive when they are signed up to a Plone site?

Comment: This is a completely appropriate question about Plone -- the person is asking how to customize a specific template that is part of Plone. As you can see from the over 1700 other questions about Plone, most questions about customization require programming, and StackOverflow is a prime place for Plone community tech support questions. This is not a question about "general computing hardware or software." In the future, please refrain from closing questions you don't understand. :-)

Comment: I'll need to word my Plone customization questions more carefully to avoid this misunderstanding in the future.

Comment: @sdupton As noted in the rejection of your edit, the question's body is not the place to make a plea to re-open a question. It is also not the place to try to educate users on how to vote/flag/etc. Just make an effort to improve the question, don't add fluff that looks like it came from the OP.

Comment: @JonStahl Would you say that it demonstrates minimal understanding? That is another reason to close a question as off-topic. I am not making a judgement; I did not vote/flag the question. But at a glance, it does not look like this question shows much research effort. Am I incorrect in that assumption?

Comment: I think what set off this whole thing was the fact that I tagged the question with too many tags. It is specific to the Plone community and could easily be misunderstood by a casual reader. Since then the additional tags have been removed. In the future I'll try to be more Plone specific when tagging questions like this. This is a bit of an anomally as I really had no sample code to show or discuss, the most that I could add to the question is to say that I had been scouring the documentation to locate where to make the change.

Comment: @Gray I would not say it demonstrates minimal understanding. Although the question seems quite simple, in this case, the message is hidden in a not-very-obvious place and there are a couple of not-so-obvious things to keep in mind where doing a customization like this. Also: the OP is well-known to me and many other frequent Plone question-answerers, and we know that he has more than "minimal understanding" of Plone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The template lives at ZMI>portal_skins>PasswordReset>registered_notify_template. If you are doing a multilingual site, you may need to provide custom translations as well. Maurits Van Rees provides some tips for doing this at: http://maurits.vanrees.org/weblog/archive/2010/10/i18n-plone-4/

Comment: Jon, 
I appreciate that you ignored those who were so quick to judge this as an off-topic question. 
I've added the customizations to my add-on now and all works as expected.